# Яка різниця між словами впертий та наполегливий?

Tags: значення-слів

На мою думку ці слова описують одну і ту ж рису характеру. Різниця лише в суб'єктивна. Хтось може це розцінювати як позитивна риса а хтось як негативна.

Comment: Словник української мови: [впертий](http://sum.in.ua/s/upertyj), [наполегливий](http://sum.in.ua/s/napoleghlyvyj).

Comment: УПЕРТИЙ = Який намагається все робити по-своєму, настоює на своєму, інколи наперекір здоровому глузду; непоступливий.

Наполеглевий = Завзятий, стійкий, непохитний у здійсненні, досягненні певної мети.

Як обєктивно відрізнити де що? Яка саме дія чи бездіяльність вкаже на різницю?

Comment: "інколи наперекір здоровому глузду" є тільки в одному тлумаченні - в "упертий". Крім того упертий "робить по-своєму", а у наполегливого акцент на досягненні мети, тобто він може робити і не "по-своєму", головне для нього - досягнення мети.